# first box still at top other box below the first box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

First box at top other boxes below the first box step by step.

```
** [jsfiddle]https://jsfiddle.net/Baloch007/9jo8tka5/14/**
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Baloch007/9jo8tka5/14/

Comment: You should have a look at me answer down below

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```js
 var i = 2;
 $('input[type=button]').click(function() {
   $('#wrapper').append("<span>Box " + i + "</span>");
   i++;
    if(i >= 8){
     $(this).hide();
    }
 })
```

```css
span {
  width: 40px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <span>Box 1</span>
</div>
<input type='button' value='+' />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<ul id="Compare-to-add">
<div id="copy" style="display:none">
<li>Box</li>
</div>
<li>Box1</li>
<input type="hidden" id="max" name="max" value="1"/>
<li id="added-more">
<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
</li>

</ul>
```

And script

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#added-more').click(function() {
    var max=parseInt($('#max').val())+1;
    $('#copy li').html('Box'+max);
    var paste = $('#copy li').clone();
    $('#Compare-to-add').append(paste);
   $('#max').val(max);
    if ($("#Compare-to-add li:visible").size() == 9 )
    {
     $('#added-more').hide();
    }
  })
  });
```